# how to bind integer value of enum to datagridtextcolumn in wpf

Tags: wpf, enums, datagrid

I Want to bind Enum int value to datagridtextboxcolumn.
I use code below

```
public enum Enm_Purchase_Ret : short
{
    Purchase = 1,
    Sale = 2,
    Return = 3
}


public class Vm_Purchase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Enumitem EnumItem = new Enumitem { Enm_Purchase_Rets = Enm_Purchase_Ret.Purchase };
    public Vm_Purchase()
    {

    }
    public class Enumitem
    {
        public Enm_Purchase_Ret Enm_Purchase_Rets { get; set; }

    }

    public Enumitem TestenumClass
    {
        get { return this.EnumItem; }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new 
            PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In XAML

```
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Value" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GetEnumValues}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100"
             SelectedItemBinding ="{Binding Enm_Purchase_Rets, Mode=TwoWay}" />


            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding xxx}" Header="Enum Id" Width="80" />
```

Here I want to bind Enum Value ie. 1,2,3 etc in xxx posotion

As I am not much expert in wpf, Please help how to bind this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

DataGridTextColumn displays result of `ToString()` method call. It is possible to get numeric value of enum by using ToString with format "D". To get the same result with binding add StringFormat:

```
Binding="{Binding Path=Enm_Purchase_Rets, StringFormat='\{0:D\}'}"
```

Comment: I tried like this                                          
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Value" ItemsSource="{Binding 
    Source={StaticResource GetEnumValues}, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  SelectedValuePath ="
    {Binding Path=Enm_Purchase_Rets, StringFormat='\{0:D\}'}"  
    Width="100"  SelectedItemBinding ="{Binding Enm_Purchase_Rets, Mode=TwoWay}"/>                                                                                           
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Enm_Purchase_Rets, StringFormat='\{0:D\}'}" Header="Enum Id"  Width="80" />

Comment: But I Get no value in DataGridTextColumn .

Comment: @babucr, please give more details about your view models. my suggestion should work for any `enum` property - **make sure that Path uses correct name of property from view model**. what is DataContext and ItemsSource of DataGrid? does DataGridTextColumn display enum names/anything at all without StringFormat? (if not - it is incorrect binding path)